# Will it be very inefficient to do a floating point calculation for every edge in a graph algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, graph

I have a large data-set with thousands of nodes and hundreds of thousands of edges.

I want the edge weight between two nodes to be the inverse of the number of edges connecting them.

I store all of the edges between two distinct nodes in their own container, so I can quickly return the number of edges between any two nodes by returning the size of the container.

Will it be too inefficient to compute the edge weights ((float)1/container.size()) every time I need to use them in a path finding algorithm? Should I consider storing the most up to date edge weight?

Comment: Why not try and compare runtimes?

Comment: Are you essentially asking how efficient is floating point division CPUs?

Comment: What's the alternative? Efficiency is only relevant if there's a choice between things that achieve the same goal.

Comment: This is a space vs performance issue. If you find there's enough memory left for storing such an intermediate result and it reduces your computation time, then do it. No one can tell from here. Maybe you can optimize the computation to work with container.size() directly, instead of the inverse.